# What are the index symbols for Etrade API?

Tags: python, c#

I am kind of lost on what would be a symbol one needs to send to the Etrade API to get the NASDAQ quote?

var quoteRequest = new RestRequest($"v1/market/quote/**^IXIC**.json");

This doesn't seem to work i.e. will not understand the ^IXIC symbol